# Is there a way to get parent domain using Node.js domain module?

Tags: node.js

Consider this example:

```
const domain = require('domain');

const main = () => {
  const d0 = domain.create();

  d0.name = 'd0';

  d0.run(() => {
    const d1 = domain.create();

    d1.name = 'd1';

    d1.run(() => {
      // Is there a way to get reference to d0 using `process`?
      console.log(process.domain.name);
    });
  });
};

main();
```

Is there a generic way (without modifying `d0` or `d1`) to get a reference to `d0` from `d1` context using `process`?

(`d0` is available in scope for demonstration purposes only.)

The intent is to get references to all parent domains.

The use case is that I am designing a [logger](https://github.com/gajus/roarr) that will inherit properties from all parent domains.

The challenge is that even if I establish a convention to somehow track the parent domain, it would be broken as soon as there is any other domain (by another script not aware of the convention) in my domain hierarchy.

In an ideal world, every domain would have `parentDomain` property by default, though that *appears* to not exist.

Comment: Can you provide an example where `d0` is not in scope of the function being executed by `d1.run()`? As is, this question does not make sense because you can simply use `d0`

Comment: The intent is to get references to all parent domains, however many there are. The use case is that I am designing a logger that will inherit properties from all parent domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find active domains by order in `domain._stack`. It's not documented, but `domain` is frozen, so it isn't going anywhere.

Also, you might want to consider moving away from `domain` to `async_hooks` or an `async_hooks` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parent through args (https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain_run_fn_args)

Sample below

```
const domain = require('domain');

const main = () => {
  const d0 = domain.create();

  d0.name = 'd0';

  d0.run(() => {
    const d1 = domain.create();

    d1.name = 'd1';
    d1.run((parent) => {

      console.log(process.domain.name);
      console.log('parent:', parent.name);
    }, process.domain);
  });
};
main();
```

Comment: What about accessing the parent of a parent?, i.e. I am in a domain at the moment and I want to find all parent domains.

Comment: You could have parent domain in stack of array and pass it as args

Comment: The challenge is that even if I establish a convention to somehow track the parent domain, it would be broken as soon as there is any other domain (by another script not aware of the convention) in my domain hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to monkey-patch `domain`, e.g.

```js
const domain = require('domain');

const originalCreate = domain.create;

domain.create = (...args) => {
  const parentDomain = process.domain || null;

  const nextDomain = originalCreate(...args);

  nextDomain.parentDomain = parentDomain;

  return nextDomain;
};
```

This way every domain would have access to the parent domain via `parentDomain`, e.g.

```js
const findParentDomainNames = () => {
  const parentDomainNames = [];

  let currentDomain = process.domain;

  while (currentDomain && currentDomain.parentDomain) {
    currentDomain = currentDomain.parentDomain;

    parentDomainNames.push(currentDomain.name);
  }

  return parentDomainNames;
};

const main = () => {
  const d0 = domain.create();

  d0.name = 'd0';

  d0.run(() => {
    const d1 = domain.create();

    d1.name = 'd1';

    d1.run(() => {
      const d2 = domain.create();

      d2.name = 'd2';

      d2.run(() => {
        console.log(findParentDomainNames());
      });
    });
  });
};

main();
```

The above prints:

```js
[
  'd1',
  'd0'
]
```

Here is an example use case: [Roarr](https://github.com/gajus/roarr#roarr-api-adopt) logger uses `parentDomain` to automatically propagate asynchronous context information to all loggers performing that task.

Comment: I will write a PR to add this to Node.js core.

Comment: I have since abstracted the above logic into a module https://github.com/gajus/domain-parent

Comment: I have implemented a sample use case https://github.com/gajus/roarr#roarr-api-adopt

Comment: Article on the subject https://dev.to/gajus/ultimate-guide-to-concurrent-logging-in-node-js-18h7